# Does this notion of "$\mathcal{F}$-digraph" appear in the literature?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, graph-theory, directed-graphs

By a *digraph*, I mean a [quiver](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver) with no multiple edges. So in particular:

- Loops are okay.
- An infinite set of vertexes is okay.

Furthermore, I will tend to identify each digraph with its underlying set of vertexes. For example, if $Y$ and $X$ are digraphs, then by a *function* $X \rightarrow Y$, I just mean a function from the vertex set of $X$ into the vertex set of $Y$.

Now given a digraph $X$, we get a function $\mathrm{out}_X : X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ that assigns to each vertex of $X$ its set of "outbound neighbours." Furthermore, given digraphs $Y$ and $X$, it can be seen that a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a homomorphism iff $(\mathrm{out}_Y \circ f)(x) \supseteq (\mathcal{P}(f) \circ \mathrm{out}_X)(x)$ for all $x \in X$, where $\mathcal{P}(f) : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$ is the "direct image function" corresponding to $f$, sometimes denoted $f_*$. We can also go back the other way; if we're given a function $o:X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$, we get a corresponding digraph structure on $X$ by asserting that there's an arc $x \rightarrow x'$ iff $x' \in o(x).$

This allows us to define "$\mathcal{F}$-digraphs" such that the usual notion is recovered when $\mathcal{F}$ is the covariant powerset functor. In what follows, think:

- $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{Pos}$
- $\mathbf{S}= \mathbf{Set}$
- the distinguished profunctor is $\mathbf{Set}(-,U-),$ where $U : \mathbf{Pos} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ is the underlying set functor.
- $\mathcal{F}$ is the **covariant** powerset functor $\mathcal{P} : \mathbf{Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{Pos}$.

> **Definition.** Let $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ denote categories together with a distinguished profunctor $\mathbf{S} \nrightarrow \mathbf{P}$ that is $\mathbf{Pos}$-enriched. Then for each functor
>   $\mathcal{F} : \mathbf{S} \rightarrow \mathbf{P}$ we define that a
>   $\mathcal{F}$-digraph is an object $X$ of $\mathbf{S}$ together with
>   an arrow $\mathrm{out}_X : X \rightarrow \mathcal{F}X$ (living in
>   the distinguished profunctor). Furthermore, we assert that given $\mathcal{F}$-digraphs $Y$ and $X$, a morphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is just an $\mathbf{S}$-morphism satisfying $\mathrm{out}_Y \circ f \geq \mathcal{F}(f) \circ \mathrm{out}_X$.

We can also get finite digraphs by taking $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{FinSet}$. Anyway, I'd like to know more.

> **Question.** Does this notion of "$\mathcal{F}$-digraph" appear in the literature? If so, where?